# How to load text data without full rollback(Copy / PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I load text information by using 'Copy' command and it works.
However, sometimes in case there are error in loading the text, all of rows are roll backed.

Is there any way to discard only rows having error, so the rest of rows are loaded successfully?

Comment: The usual way to deal with this is to load the data into a staging table, and then copy only the valid data into the real table (e.g. using `insert .. on conflict ..`

Comment: In this issue, the dirty data was 2016-02-30 and column datatype is timestamp, so the value is out of scope. True that that is very abnormal data. I was wondering if there is an option to discard that. Staging table way looks good. I will try that. Thank you.